# Confusing prototype behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I don't understand why the following is happening:

```
function Class() {}
Class.prototype.foo = {a: 1};
Class.prototype.bar = 1;

x = new Class();
y = new Class();

y.foo.a = 2;
y.bar = 2;

x.foo.a; //2
x.bar; //1
```

When I set `y.foo.a` to 2, it seems to be performing the same operation as `y.constructor.prototype.foo.a = 2`. Why would this be, given that `y.bar = 2` doesn't affect `y.constructor.prototype.bar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading `y.foo` but assigning to `y.bar`.  These are different operations with different semantics.  Setting `y.foo.bar` must first read `y.foo`: it looks for the value of `foo` in `y`, fails to find it, then looks in `y`'s prototype, discovers an object, and only then modifies that object.  assigning y.bar simply looks up y and then modifies it. `x.bar` and `y.bar` then denote different objects, while `x.foo` and and `y.foo` denote the same object.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing prototype properties with properties that are *local* to the object instance. Using `y.bar = 2`, you are assigning an instance property (`bar`) to the *instance* `y`. In interpreting a property (`bar`) is first looked up within the instance itself. If it isn't found there, the lookup continues in the instances prototype. Now you assigned `bar` to `y`, so `y.bar = 2`, but instance `x` has no knowledge of it, so for `x` the lookup continues using its prototype (that's `prototype.bar`, still with value 1).

For `y.foo.a`, there is no instance property `foo` in `y`, so it's looked up in its prototype. There it's found, and the property `a` is assigned the new value. Because you are thereby changing a value of the `Class.prototype` property `foo`, it's also represented in `x`.

If you want to change bar in its prototype (so originating from instance `y`), you'll have to use the prototype of `y`'s `constructor` (which is `Class`):

```
y.constructor.prototype.bar = 2;
```

May [mr Douglas Crockford](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook) can clarify things for you (jump to around minute 23 in the video for prototypal inheritance)?

Answer (score 0):

Reading an attribute does search in the prototype object, if it is not defined in the main object.

Setting an attribute does ever set it to the main object and NEVER to the prototype object.

Because of this, it is ever a bad idea to define something other than functions, or values that will never change in prototype objects.

To really understand what happens, I recommend you to experiment with the

```
 __proto__
```

attribute. I know, not all browsers do support it, but it really helps you understand how prototyping in JavaScript works.