# Javascript for-in and built-in properties

Tags: javascript

Why are the built-in properties on javascript objects not iterated through when using the for-in control block, while user-defined properties are?

For example:

```
var y = 'car';
for (var j in y)
{
    console.log(j);
}
```

Will print:

```
0
1
2
```

Even though String.prototype has properties for length, replace, substring, etc.

If extending the prototype, however, any new properties *are* iterated over:

```
String.prototype.foo = 7;
var y = 'car';
for (var j in y)
{
    console.log(j);
}
```

Will print:

```
0
1
2
foo
```

Comment: FYI: The order of iteration over JavaScript properties is undefined.  Many implementations will return the properties in the order they were defined, in others (Versions of Opera and Safari, if I remember correctly), they could be out of order.

Comment: @mikerobi: Chrome [is pretty well known](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=883) to not iterate in the same order as other browsers.

Comment: @Andy E, that is an old issue, every version of Chrome I've used has iterated in order of definition. In order iteration leads to many developers writing defective code.  Code which appears to work, but could unexpectedly break at any time is much more dangerous than code that never works.

Comment: @mikerobi: using Chrome 11 right now, iteration isn't in order of definition. That bug is also marked **wontfix**, because the specification doesn't define the order of iteration on `for...in` loops. Developers lead to developers writing defective code, I would expect a competent JS developer to know they can't rely on these things.

Comment: @Andy E, I found portions of the jQueryUI API that made this assumption.  The method in question was later written to accept arrays as well as objects, but it goes to show that this incompetency is more widespread than you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the built-in properties are marked as "non-enumerable" internally. This means, naturally, they aren't enumerated.

Edit: as Andy kindly pointed out, you *can* set `enumerable : false` in the current version of JavaScript using `defineProperty`. However, this seems to not be supported Opera at all; IE 8 only supports it on DOM objects and Safari only supports it on *non*-DOM objects ([defineProperty on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (look towards bottom of file for browser support)).

All this cross-browser fun means that you probably shouldn't rely on this behavior if you need consistent browser support.

Here is how you could define a non-enumerable property:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "foo", {value : 7, enumerable : false});
```

You don't actually need to include `enumerable : false`—it is `false` by default when calling `defineProperty`.

Comment: Incorrect at the end.  The current version of ECMAScript/JavaScript has methods named `defineProperty` and `defineProperties` which, among other things, allow you to set `enumerable: false`.

Answer (score 3):

There is [propertyIsEnumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) method, which returns a boolean indicating if the internal ECMAScript [DontEnum attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute) is set (also note the terrible disagreements amongst implementations). As said above, you cannot set `DontEnum`, but only query via `propertyIsEnumerable`.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
var y = 'car';
for (var j in y)  {
  console.log(j);
}
```

you are iterating through the properties of a String instance, which is treated as an array of characters. In this case the array has 3 elements, so it's 'properties' are 0,1,2. If you `console.logged` `y[j]`, you should have seen `'c','a','r'`.

Now if you want to see the prototype properties/methods, you should query the prototype of y's `constructor` prototype (which is `String`):

```
for (var j in y.constructor.prototype)
{
    console.log(j);
}
```

In

```
String.prototype.foo = 7;
var y = 'car';
for (var j in y)  {
  console.log(j);
}
```

you added a property `foo` to `String.prototype`. Adding a property to the constructors (String) prototype makes it available to all instances. The string literal `y` is an instance of `String`, hence you see `foo` appearing in `y`, when enumerating through it's properties.

See also: [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929713/confusing-prototype-behavior-in-javascript/5930144#5930144)

Answer (score 1):

To extend on everyone elses answer you can mark your own properties as non enumerable by  using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
var o = {},
    def = Object.defineProperty;

def(o, "myProperty", {
   "value": 42,
   "enumerable": false,
   "writeable": true,
   "configurable": true
});
```

Note that these properties default to false so you can just not include `"enumerable"` to set it to false.