# JavaScript native objects with extended prototype and "for-in" loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, embedded-object

I have extended `Array` prototype:

```
if(typeof Array.prototype.filter === 'undefined') Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/){
  var len = this.length;
  if(typeof fun != "function") throw new TypeError();

  var res = [], thisp = arguments[1];

  for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(i in this){
      var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
      if(fun.call(thisp, val, i, this)) res.push(val);
    }
  }

  return res;
};
```

For example I have created array:

```
var A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
```

Then I added extra properties to it, that I will use:

```
A.creator = 'Rustam';
A.created = new Date();
```

If I will use `for-in` loop, and browser has not built-in support for `Array.filter`, it will go through `A.filter`.

I know this way:

```
for(var p in A) {
  if (!A.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue
  console.log(p)
};
```

**Is there a way to make `A.filter` hidden in `for-in` without using `hasOwnProperty`?**

---

**UPDATE to answer.** Browser support:

- IE9+
- FF4+
- Chrome
- Opera 11.6+
- Safari 5+

Comment: I don't understand the question. How do you mean hidden? And on a point of clarity, when you append named properties to your array, it becomes an object - it is no longer an array.

Comment: @Utkanos Try to do this with empty object and get length from it. This is not object. jQuery selectors built on arrays with extra properties.

Comment: @Rustam - jQuery returns objects, not arrays. Try it - `$('*') instanceof Array` (false). They are array-*like* objects - not actually arrays.

Comment: @Utkanos try to create an empty object {} and then use it like array: A[1] = 5; A[2] = 7; then try to get .length. You will not get it. jQuery uses base prototype of Array.

Comment: @Utkanos What does this question have to do with jQuery?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to 'extend' the native `for in` language construct to internally use `Array.prototype.filter` instead of having to explicitly call `hasOwnProperty()`, is that right?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940837/javascript-for-in-and-built-in-properties

Comment: @Chris Francis No, I want to extend Array.

Comment: @Rustam Then you should loop using `for(var i=0; i<array_name.length; i++)`, and **not** via `for(var i in array_name)`.

Comment: @Rob W No, I need extended Array with properties. Array for length and numeric values. Properties for working with data - is is very useful. For-in is used by another programmer to get data and he don't want to use hasOwnProperty in for-in loop. But because this will not work in IE8, I can not extend Array.

Comment: @Rustam I understand that you want to extend `Array.prototype`. My previous comment was pointing to the fact that `for(.. in ..)` loops are considered bad practice for arrays. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays.

Comment: @Rustam - do you recall your own comment? You mentioned jQuery, not me.

Comment: @Utkanos This was Rob W question, not my.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To define a property which does not show up in loops, use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'filter', {value:'XYZ'});
```

This extends `Array.prototype` with a property called `filter` with default property descriptors, including `enumerable: false`, which causes the property to not show up in `for( .. in ..)` loops.

#### References

- [`Object.defineProperty` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [`Object.defineProperty` at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548687(v=vs.94).aspx)

PS: Will not work on *older browsers* I don't have the browser compatibility matrix for this API.

Comment: Please describe browser support and links to specification

Comment: @Rustam here are the links you asked for
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548687(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: This is ECMAScript 5 syntax, so browser support will be lacking unless you can 'shim' the functionality.

Comment: browser compatibility matrix is included in the MDN link.